# Map one asset attribute field to another using MySQL

Tags: assets, relations, database, mysql

In Craft, is it possible to map one field containing string value to another?

I have a bunch of image assets that has a title field and `altTag` fields. I've entered data into the alt tag field, but now I would like to copy that data for each asset into the `title` field for that same asset.

Doing this manually for each asset would take forever, but it sounds like something that could be done with mysql queries.

I poked around the database to see where the `title` fields or the `altTag` fields are stored. The `altTag` field is in the `craft_fields` table, and I can see all my assets in the `craft_assetfiles` table. But `title` is not one of the columns in this table, I do see the `filename` column. But I think my knowledge of the structure of craft tables are lacking to find where the values for the `altTag` fields are stored or how to copy the value of each alt tag into the corresponding title field for the asset.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the `craft_content` table. There you should find the `title` column and the `field_altTag` column. You could set the `title` to the `field_altTag` value where that value is not empty.

Back up the database first...